# Share data between react routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to make a dashboard for my discord bot with react, I managed to make a dashboard page which list all the servers with a button to manage them, so when user click on that button I  redirect the user to a different route. The problem is how I can share clicked server's data with the other route.

**What I have already tried :**

1. I tried to create a `GuildContext` and save server data when button is clicked. It was working fine but when I refresh the page `GuildContext` get destroyed.
2. I put the data in the URL as search parameters but that just looks so bad.

Please help me out how I can share this data with other routes.

Comment: The best approach I think is to put an id of the server in the URL and then on the next screen to retrieve the server data by this id. Is it possible to do it this way?

Comment: I was thinking about this too but it is okay to request the guild from backend in every route?

Comment: I don't know what a "guild" is but I cannot think of another way to store the data on page refresh. Also if you send the URL to somebody else it's impossible to send it anywhere else than the URL.

Comment: ohh sorry, guild just mean a server. Thanks for giving your time. I will implement this.

Comment: If you don't want data as query param you could use localStorage to save references, but it's not the best way. I would say that the correct one is to send query params.